# Hosting an aspx web service on a Linux Server

Tags: asp.net, cpanel

I'm tryig to get my first restful api to hosted on my Linux server (which I control via cPanel), decided to make it in aspx but when I tried to host it I was told to use IIS, which I know is used to control microsoft servers, do I have to make my api on php or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why did you choose ASPX in the first place?

Comment: You might either use PHP or ASP.NET Core, which are designed to be cross platform. ASPX is part of the old ASP.NET which is Windows only.